# How to write testcase using NBehave

Tags: nbehave

I want every steps to write a Nbehave testcase. I have gone through the concept, but i don't know how to start and where to start. If any one can give an example with all the steps then it would be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

There's a full example on the NBehave documentation page.
http://nbehave.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20started&referringTitle=Documentation

However even though I really like NBehave, if you need to fit in with other DotNet tools, such as test coverage tools or CI servers, I find there is better integration with SpecFlow, http://specflow.org/